# The basis for the null space of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am given the following linear transformation

$$f: \begin{bmatrix}x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}x\\
x
\end{bmatrix}$$

and asked to select all answers which provide a basis for the null space and which correctly identify the nullity of the map.

Here are the options:

1. $$\begin{array}{cccc}
   B=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}1\\
   1\\
   1
   \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\
   1\\
   1
   \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle  &  &  & \text{null}\left(f\right)=2\end{array}$$
2. $$\begin{array}{cccc}
   B=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}1\\
   1
   \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle  &  &  & \text{null}\left(f\right)=1\end{array}$$
3. $$\begin{array}{cccc}
   B=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}0\\
   1\\
   0
   \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\
   0\\
   1
   \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle  &  &  & \text{null}\left(f\right)=1\end{array}$$
4. $$\begin{array}{cccc}
   B=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}0\\
   1\\
   1
   \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\
   1\\
   -1
   \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle  &  &  & \text{null}\left(f\right)=2\end{array}$$

We can immediately rule out option (2), as the null space is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To rule out further options, we can find the nullity. To do this, we set the codomain equal to $0$, write the linear system as an augmented matrix, perform row operations to put the matrix into row echelon form, and solve for the leading variables. We can then parameterize the kernel, which results in the following.

$$\cal{K}\left(f\right)=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}y+\begin{bmatrix}0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}z\mid y,z\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$

This tells us that $\text{null}\left(f\right)=2$. Therefore, we can rule out option (3).

To determine if option (1) and option (4) are valid, we need to show that (a) the candidate basis is linearly independent and (b) it spans the null space.

Unless I am mistaken, the null space is the same as the kernel.

I tested both (a) and (b) for options (1) and (4) and found that they both are linearly independent and span the kernel.

Here is my work for determining whether the candidate basis spans the kernel (I will omit the linear independence test because that is far simpler).

**Option 1:**

$$r\begin{bmatrix}1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}0\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$

I wrote the linear system as an augmented matrix, performed row operations to put the matrix into row echelon form, and solved for the leading variables.

$$\begin{array}{rclccrclccrcl}
0 & = & c-b &  &  & s & = & b-a &  &  & r & = & a\end{array}$$

Unless I am mistaken, this shows that the candidate basis spans the kernel.

**Option 4:**

$$r\begin{bmatrix}0\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}0\\
1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}$$

I wrote the linear system as an augmented matrix, performed row operations to put the matrix into row echelon form, and solved for the leading variables.

$$\begin{array}{rclccrclccrcl}
0 & = & 0 &  &  & s & = & -\frac{1}{2}\left(c-b\right) &  &  & r & = & \frac{1}{2}\left(b-c\right)\end{array}$$

Unless I am mistaken, this shows that the candidate basis spans the kernel.

**The answer:**

Therefore, I selected both options (1) and (4). Apparently, this is incorrect.

Does anyone know where I went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Why did you eliminate option 3?

Comment: @Bernard Because the nullity is $2$.

Comment: Are the vectors in 1 in the null space?

Comment: Precisely, you obtained a subspace of dimension $2$. Anyway, the kernel is defined by the linear equation $x=0$.

Comment: hmm, 3 has a typo, the dim. is 2 there.

Comment: @DavidMitra "Are the vectors in 1 in the null space?" - Unless I made a mistake, yes; "hmm, 3 has a typo, the dim. is 2 there." - How do you figure?

Comment: @Bernard "Precisely, you obtained a subspace of dimension $2$. Anyway, the kernel is defined by the linear equation $x=0$." - Is the kernel I listed incorrect?

Comment: It is pretty easy to see that a vector is in the kernel of this map if and only if it is of the form $(0,y,z)$. And this is precisely option 3, which there seems to be a typo because the dimension of this subspace is $2$.

Comment: The kernel  ($\mathcal K(f)=\dots$) is quite correct, that's why I don't understand this ruling out.

Comment: The image of [1,1,1] (make it a column) is not the zero vector. I see 2 independent vectors in 3. The dim. of their span is 2.

Comment: In your option 1 check, you are using the vectors in (3).

Comment: @Bernard I see. So, is ONLY option (3) correct (assuming there was a mistake)? And options (1), (2), and (4) are all incorrect?

Comment: No: option 4 also has two linearly independent vectors which are in the kernel.

Comment: @Bernard To confirm, assuming there was a typo in option (3), the answers are options (3) and (4)? If that is the case, it is possible that option (3) was NOT a typo. Therefore, option (4) is the ONLY answer.

Comment: Also, I just edited, because I provided the wrong work for Option 1.

Comment: I really think it was a typo: asserting that $B$ consists of two clearly independent vectors, and that it has dimension $1$ is quite unlikely for me. So, in my opinion, options $3$ and $4$ are the correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should eliminate option 1 at first since it cannot span ker$f$. For example, $(0,1,5) \in kerf$, but it is not included in the set in option 1.

Comment: I determined that option (1) does span the kernel. What was wrong with my work?

Comment: Hi Julian, the set under the second Option 1 (bold written), and the first Option 1 are different.